# Elastic search combining queries and nested queries together

Tags: elasticsearch

I've been reading elasticsearch queries for some time now and the documentation doesn't seem helpful for some of my queries.
I'm trying to get documents which are

```
((Field1=Keyword1 OR Field2=Keyword1) AND (Field1=Keyword2 OR Field2=Keyword2)) AND (Field3=Keyword3 ) AND (Field4!=Keyword4)).
```

The document which I refered is 
https://dzone.com/articles/23-useful-elasticsearch-example-queries and when trying to execute some of their queries in sense API extension in Chrome, it had syntax errors in it. 
Eg:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "bool" : { "should": [
                      { "match": { "title": "Elasticsearch" }},
                      { "match": { "title": "Solr" }} ] }
            },
            "must": { "match": { "authors": "clinton gormely" }},
            "must_not": { "match": {"authors": "radu gheorge" }}
        }
    }
}
```

It gives "Duplicate Must. Syntax error".

Could you help with forming my query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have must twice in same level. Try this

```
   {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [{
                    "bool" : { "should": [
                          { "match": { "title": "Elasticsearch" }},
                          { "match": { "title": "Solr" }} ] }
                }, { "match": { "authors": "clinton gormely" }}],

                "must_not": { "match": {"authors": "radu gheorge" }}
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but the question I asked is about generating new query for this
`((Field1=Keyword1 OR Field2=Keyword1) AND (Field1=Keyword2 OR Field2=Keyword2)) AND (Field3=Keyword3 ) AND (Field4!=Keyword4)).`

Comment: Did you try the query in the answer? It looks to me like it will give you results that match `((title=Elasticsearch OR title=Solr) AND (authors=clinton gormley) AND (authors!=radu gheorge))` -- just like you're asking. If it's not working you should explain how.

Comment: @dshockley are you asking me ?:)

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat -- sorry, no! I meant that your answer looks good, I was asking OP if he had tried your solution before commenting. :)

Comment: @dshockley It was joke :) sometimes OP dont want to try they want ready code to copy paste.......

Comment: Alright, Clearly you didn't get my point but if having those braces helps in building my nesting query, I'll try your suggestion, although it won't solve my problem, i'll still go ahead and accept it..

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the answer by Volodymyr, your query contains 2 must at the same level and hence the error. Look at [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/combining-filters.html) documentation to fulfil your requirement.

> must: All of these clauses must match. The equivalent of AND.
>
> must_not: All of these clauses must not match. The equivalent of NOT.
>
> should At least one of these clauses must match. The equivalent of OR.
>
> filter: Clauses that must match, but are run in non-scoring, filtering mode.